# How to change Google crawl rate in new Google search console?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, crawl-rate

Google has now completely removed the old search console (https://searchengineland.com/the-old-google-search-console-is-no-longer-available-321650) where you used to be able to request a custom crawl rate. Now in the new search console there doesn't seem to be any way to change the crawl rate. You can click on "crawl stats" under "Legacy tools and reports" but I am not getting any option there to change the crawl rate. Since Google removed the old search console 3 days ago, has anyone been able to request a custom crawl rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Click "learn more" under "Legacy tools and reports".
2. A modal help window appears with a table of links to legacy tools. Crawl rate is at the bottom.

Comment: I found it! Nice work. Cheers!!